Probability of picking a card after some have been removed
Question - From a deck of 52 cards numbered from 1 to 52, 13 cards are randomly removed. From the remaining cards, what is the probability of picking a card which is a multiple of 13?
My Solution
There are 4 cards which are multiples of 13. Since removing each card, and picking the card too are independent events, the answer will simply be the probability of each card NOT getting removed, followed by it getting picked, so
${4*(\frac{51}{52}*\frac{50}{51}...\frac{39}{40})*\frac{1}{39}}$
And so the answer is just $\frac{1}{13}$.
This question was part of an exam, and there was no answer key given. There were a few contrasting answers among my classmates. Is my answer right?

Yes.  Simpler, perhaps, to note that each card has an equal chance of being drawn in this fashion, hence each remainder $\pmod {13}$ is equally likely to be observed (as each remainder is equally represented in the original deck).
